# Are poles a problem for the animation?

Tags: animation, topology

I'm doing a character right now and i see that i created some poles beneath the limb areas. The thing is, can these poles be a problem for the animation or deformation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you don't have an excessive amount (if your topology is clean you shouldn't have many) they won't be a problem. I've never seen a character with no poles in the underarm area, and every character I've made has them and they all deform cleanly.